# Error during class serialization: type is not marked serializable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binary-serialization

I have a class marked as [Serializable]. It has a property tha I don't wan to serialize.
But at runtime I got an error during serialization.
These are my classes:

```
public interface IMyNonSerializable
{
   ...
}
public class MyNonSerializable : IMyNonSerializable
{
   ...
}
[Serializable]
public class MySerializable
{
   public string MyProp1{get;set;}
   [NonSerialized]
   public string MyProp2{get;set;}
   public IMyNonSerializable MyNonSerializableProp{get;set;}
}
```

Here the code I use to serialize my MySerializable class:

```
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone);
    formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
```

At runtime I got this error:

```
> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
  HResult=0x8013150C
  Message=Type 'MyNonSerializable' is not marked as serializable.
  Source=mscorlib
```

Is there a way to serialize my class avoiding to serialize my non-serializable class without implement ISerializable interface?

Comment: Put the `[NonSerialized]` above your `public IMyNonSerializable MyNonSerializableProp`?

Comment: [NonSerialized] can be applied on field only.

Comment: Why do you state this: "It has a property that I cannot mark [NonSerialized] because it is not serializable at all."?

Comment: @moro91 edited my question, it was a little bit confused. Thanks.

Comment: Please, I cannot emphasize this enough: **do not use `BinaryFormatter`**. It is not intended for use now. Just about **anything else** would be preferable. I would be happy to offer advice on alternatives (personally I'm partial to protobuf-net, but frankly json is fine for many things)

Comment: @MarcGravell I am interested: why BinaryFormatter is not good? I'm open to news!

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you please point out an article or something about why people shoud make different choices, with detailed infos? Thanks

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori a: it is not supported in .NET Core (and even when it works, has huge problems because of assembly movements), severely limiting your path forward, b: it is a known security hole, c: it is incredibly brittle re versioning - it **will** hurt you as you move forward: the only questions are 1) when and 2) how badly

Comment: Thank you @MarcGravell I'm going to thinking about it.

Comment: Oh, and d: it isn't great perf-wise; the good news is: it is usually *incredibly* easy to switch to an alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create backing field and apply the `[NonSerialized]` attribute to this one:

```
[Serializable]
public class MySerializable
{
    public string MyProp1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProp2 { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized]
    private IMyNonSerializable _myNonSerializableProp;
    public IMyNonSerializable MyNonSerializableProp
    {
        get { return _myNonSerializableProp; }
        set { _myNonSerializableProp = value; }
    }
}
```

If you are using C# 7.3 or later, you could use a field-targeted attribute on the auto-generated property without creating a backing field:

```
[field: NonSerialized]
public IMyNonSerializable MyNonSerializableProp { get; set; }
```